# Zero-inflated poisson model producing NaN results

Tags: poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

I have been trying to run a zero-inflated poisson model as follows:

```
Model2_2_4 <- zeroinfl(Conflict.intensity ~ Distance.from.fence + Distance.from.water + Distance.from.roads + Elevation, data = data2_2)
```

Here, `Conflict.intensity` is a continuous response variable.

[image: Zero-inflated poisson model]

Can someone help me understand why I am getting NaN values and possible ways of troubleshooting, thank you :)

Comment: Why are you using a Poisson for a continuous response variable? The Poisson distribution is integer valued. Could this be it? Also, you are fitting a 5-coefficient Poisson AND a 5-coefficient binomial (the zero inflated term). That's a lot of coefficients if you don't have a large sample size. Can you simplify the model?